# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props, heroicons

I got this error when I tried to use props. In SideBarMenuItems.js
export default function SideBarMenu({text, Icon}) {
return (


{text}

)
}
Here, I pass text and Icon as props and when I used in SideBar.js

I got the above error.

Comment: add **SideBar.js** component